# Not Capturing FB Like Event

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

I have placed FB like button using iframe code...

Here is the code for Like Button:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fmadamebridal.com%2Fdev%2Fcheckout%2Fonepage%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And I am using this code to capture the FB like event...

Here is the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You liked THISSS Yeaa');
        }
    );
};
```

But... it is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? How can we help you if you don't even tell us your problem?

Comment: @Doorknob -- "Not working" means that... Script doesn't alert 'You Liked THISSS Yeaa' when someone click on 'Like' button

Comment: @Mohal - You need to help us to help you. *"It's not working"* is definitely **NOT** a description of any kind of problem. So, what have you tried in terms of debugging? Have you checked your console? What are the errors that get thrown? Have you ensured `fbAsyncInit` is getting called? Does `all.js` get included? Have you called `FB.init()`?

Comment: So much for the criticism and so much for the lack of knowledge. I guess StackOverflow is becoming more and more criticism oriented and less solution oriented. If you guys were really here to help then you could have solved my issue in less than a minute… I am a newbie to Facebook API/SDK. So, didn’t know how to ask the question. But if someone was wise enough then he/she could have told me that FB Like button capture is not possible if you are using “iframe” code to display the “Like” button. Anyhow, I have solved my problem. Thanx for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all, when you go to the doctor you don't say, I feel pain and expect him to cure you. Are you loading javascript sdk properly?

This code should work for you, unless you have other scripts firing errors and prevent facebook sdk of working normally.

Put this code next to the your `<body>` tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {alert('You liked THISSS Yeaa'); });
            };


          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
          (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
           }(document));
    </script>
```

Comment: I know my question was not clear but the issue wasn't the code. Actually, the container div for FB Like button was hidden when page loaded. So, JavaScript SDK was not finding the "Like" button.